# Ubuntu Logs off on shutdown, Proper shutdown/restart too doesnt work

Tags: shutdown, reboot, power-management

I don't know what i did or what happened?

but my ubuntu logs off on clicking shutdown...

running the shutdown or reboot command too doesn't shutdown....

how can i find the log?

all i know is there is a message saying ....

```
Power_table_CMD wait for 500 sec
```

and something similar

it gets stuck on Ubuntu Plymouth...

I have to long press the power button on my Laptop to shut it off

here is what i get when i try to shutdown...

[image]

Comment: any1 ? help please?

Answer (score 2):

Google translated answer:

> Friend I am having the same problem, had to restart with the command `sudo reboot`

Original answer:

Amigo estou com o mesmo problema, tive que reinicaiar com o comando `sudo reboot`

Comment: why dont u upvote the q so it gets solved